# Problem with images when no dimension in the URL

Tags: images

I have a problem on my site that when I open an image's direct link it goes to 404 page.

Here:

> http://byrnecoatings.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/20140710_144125.jpg

With the dimensions it opens perfectly fine

Here:

> http://byrnecoatings.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/20140710_144125-1024x576.jpg

Comment: have you verified that the image actually exists in the uploads folder? are you using a plugin or theme that deletes the original file on upload?

Comment: yes the image exists on the disk

Comment: the image size is little big (3MB+) do you think thats the factor?

Comment: the possibiliti *only* that your file is not exist. period. size doesn't matter.

Comment: the file exists. period.

Comment: If the file exists, something outside of WordPress is making your server think it doesn't. The htaccess file has rules that forward requests for non-physical files to WordPress,  the fact that you get a WordPress 404 means the problem is before WordPress receives the request.

Comment: any suggetions on that, how to solve it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was problem in my `.htaccess` file, that was preventing direct image urls